# Removing duplicate event listeners

Tags: javascript, events, listener, addeventlistener

I have been trying to find a way to remove an event listener. I made a function that will add an event listener to a button but if the function runs again I want the event listener to be removed and added again. But instead it will just add another event listener and when I click on the button it will run the event listener function twice. Or even if I can just prevent it from adding a second event listener to the button would work too.

Here is the code

```html
<button id="myId">My Button</button>
 
 
 
<script>
 
 
 
myFunction()
myFunction()
 
function myFunction() {
     var el = document.getElementById('myId')
 
     var listenerFn = function () {
          console.log('My Message')
     }
 
     el.removeEventListener('click', listenerFn)
 
     el.addEventListener('click', listenerFn)
}
 
 
 
</script>
```

Any tips would be most helpful.

UPDATE:

@FathiAlqadasi answer is the best so far for my issue. But I should of shown more of the code. the listener function is dynamic and can vary on what it does. Here is a another example of what I mean.

```
<button id="myId">My Button</button>



<script>

myFunctionA()
myFunctionA()



function myFunctionA() {
    var el = document.getElementById('myId')
    myFunctionB()
    function myFunctionB() {
        if (el.innerHTML === 'My Button') {
            var listenerFn = function () {
                console.log('My Message 1')
            }

               el.removeEventListener('click', listenerFn);

            el.addEventListener('click', listenerFn);
        }

        else {
            var listenerFn = function () {
                console.log('My Message 2')
            }

               el.removeEventListener('click', listenerFn);

            el.addEventListener('click', listenerFn);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

UPDATE 2:

Thank you @ for the code. Here is the code in a neat codebox

```
<button id="myId">My Button</button>

<script>
    var listenerFn;
    myFunction();
    myFunction()
    function myFunction() {
        var el = document.getElementById('myId')
        el.removeEventListener('click', listenerFn);
        listenerFn = function() {
            console.log('My Message')
        }
        el.addEventListener('click', listenerFn, false);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this example, we add and remove the listener in the same function as alternative to prevent redundant listeners.

```js
function callbackFunction() {
  console.log('Callback function was called.')
}

function addRemoveListener() {
  let el = document.getElementById('btn-test')

  el.removeEventListener('click', callbackFunction)
  el.addEventListener('click', callbackFunction)
}

addRemoveListener()
addRemoveListener()
```

```html
<button id="btn-test">Button</button>
```

Comment: Your code does work but not when the functions are dynamic which is what I should of shown in my first post. Read my update to understand more above.

Comment: You need to save a reference to the handler function to be able to delete it.
Try this code I only defined the listenerFn variable out side of the myFunction 





               
<button id="myId">My Button</button>
<script>
var removeListener = false;
var listenerFn;
myFunction()
myFunction()

function myFunction() {
     var el = document.getElementById('myId')
el.removeEventListener('click', listenerFn);
     listenerFn = function () {
          console.log('My Message')
     }
     el.addEventListener('click', listenerFn,false);
}
</script>

Answer (score 2):

When working with event listeners, I like to store them in an object so that I can keep track of what has been registered and easily remove them where necessary.

In your case, a simple boolean will do created in the global scope to check whether you need to remove the listener or not. (set to true after adding the listener).

```
<button id="myId">My Button</button>



<script>

var removeListener = false;

myFunction()
myFunction()

function myFunction() {
     var el = document.getElementById('myId')

     var listenerFn = function () {
          console.log('My Message')
     }

     if (removeListener) el.removeEventListener('click', listenerFn)

     el.addEventListener('click', listenerFn);
     removeListener = true;
}



</script>
```

**UPDATE**
As per your update, I have a revised answer. Its still not clear to me why you are calling the function twice, but we'll take that as a given.

```
<button id="myId">My Button</button>



<script>
var listeners = {};

myFunctionA();
myFunctionA();



function myFunctionA() {
    var listenerFn1 = function() { //These functions need to be distinct so that we can refer to them when removing
        console.log('My Message 1')
    };

    var listenerFn2 = function() { //We actually didn't need to move these out from where they were, but its a little easier to read this way
        console.log('My Message 2')
    };

    function myFunctionB() {
        if (el.innerHTML === 'My Button') {
            if (listeners[el]) el.removeEventListener('click', listeners[el]);
            el.addEventListener('click', listenerFn1);
            listeners[el] = listenerFn1; //This could be expanded to account for different events, but keeping it simple for this scenario
        }
        else {
            if (listeners[el]) el.removeEventListener('click', listeners[el]);
            el.addEventListener('click', listenerFn2);
            listeners[el] = listenerFn2;
        }
    }

    var el = document.getElementById('myId');
    myFunctionB();
}
</script>
```

The main point here is to have an object that stores the functions being called when the event is triggered. The object could allow for different events, e.g.:

```
var listener = {};
var el = document.getElementById('myId');

...

//Check if a click listener exists for el
if (listener[el] && listener[el].click) {
  //Remove currently registered listener
  el.removeEventListener('click', listener[el].click);
}
listener[el] = listener[el] || {}; //If listener[el] does not exist, create it
listener[el].click = function() {
  //We can use an anonymous function in this case because we do not need to compare it to any other functions
  console.log('Click 1');
};
el.addEventListener('click', listener[el].click);
```

If you want to allow multiple events to be attached to a listener, you cannot use anonymous functions as you want to make sure that you do not add the same function twice.

```
var listener = {};
var el = document.getElementById('myId');

...

var eventHandler1 = function() {
  console.log('eventHandler1');
};
var eventHandler2 = function() {
  console.log('eventHandler2');
};
//Check if a click listener exists for el that uses eventHandler1
if (listener[el] && listener[el].click && listener[el].click.includes(eventHandler1)) {
  //Remove listener with eventHandler1
  el.removeEventListener('click', listener[el].click.filter(function(val) {
    return val === eventHandler1;
  }));
}
listener[el] = listener[el] || {}; //If listener[el] does not exist, create it
listener[el].click = listener[el].click || [];
listener[el].click.push(eventHandler1);
el.addEventListener('click', eventHandler1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS, functions are object type which means they are reference type. I mean every single time you you run your `myFunction`;

```
function myFunction() {
     var el         = document.getElementById('myId'),
         listenerFn = function () {
                        console.log('My Message')
                      };

     el.removeEventListener('click', listenerFn)
     el.addEventListener('click', listenerFn)
}
```

you create a separate `listenerFn` hence `removeEventLister()` can tell them apart since the argument of `removeEventListener()` must reference the previously set event listener function.

You should do as follows;

```html
<button id="myId">My Button</button>

<script>

function listenerFn() {
  console.log('My Message')
}

function myFunction() {
   var el = document.getElementById('myId')
   el.removeEventListener('click', listenerFn)
   el.addEventListener('click', listenerFn)
}

myFunction();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Or even if I can just prevent it from adding a second event listener to the button would work too.

This example will add a listener only once. I'm using the `dataset` as flag to know if the button is listening of not. However, I strongly recommend to use the [`GlobalEventHandlers.onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) like here: `btnRemove.onclick = removeBtnListener` it is more clean and also you will be 100% sure that there is only one function added.

```js
function callbackFunction() {
  console.log('Callback function was called.')
}

function removeBtnListener() {
  const btn = document.getElementById('btn-test')

  if (btn.dataset.listening) {
    btn.removeEventListener('click', callbackFunction)
    delete btn.dataset.listening

    console.log('Listener removed.')
  }
}

function initListener() {
  let btn = document.getElementById('btn-test')

  if (!btn.dataset.listening) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', callbackFunction)
    btn.dataset.listening = true

    console.log('Listener added.')
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  let btnRemove = document.getElementById('btn-remove')
  btnRemove.onclick = removeBtnListener

  initListener()
  initListener()
  initListener()
  initListener()
}
```

```html
<button id="btn-test">Button</button>
<button id="btn-remove">Remove Listener</button>
```